# Как в Google maps сделать кнопки управления круглыми?

Tags: android

Как в Google maps сделать кнопки управления круглыми?

Они сейчас квадратные. Такие кнопки как zoom MyLocation и т.д. В гугл картах от Google кнопки эти круглые. Как сделать их таковыми?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самому:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/MyLocation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_location" />
```

В классе:

```
private LatLng fromPosition;

FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.MyLocation);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(fromPosition)      
                .zoom(17)                   
                .bearing(180)                
                .tilt(80)                  
                .build(); 
               map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        }
    });
```

P.S. Готовых решений от Google нет. Придется делать самому. Если делать такое не хочется, то лучше оставить старые квадратные решения.